# Cannot create volume of more than 2 GBs in openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I have installed OpenStack on my local machine. I am able to perform every functionality such as uploading image, creating and launching instance, associating floating ip etc. But I cannot create volume of more than 2 gb. If I create any volume of more than 2 GB then it gives me the status "error" on my dashboard. Less than 2 GBs are getting created.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your VG might only be 2G in size?  Try looking deeper in the volume logs, or do a vgs/lvs and have a look at your available vs used capacities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DevStack instance, the default volume backing file is 5GB. Check how much of your volume backing file is free/used by running 'pvs' or 'vgs' on command line (as a root user).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. [This is how I got it solved.](http://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/openstack-increase-volume-capacity/)

Execute "vgs" command to see the volume groups of the server. You will see something similar to the below, a volume group which has VSize 2GB.

```
$vgs
  VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  stack-volumes   3   1   0 wz--n-  10.00g 10.00g
  stratos1        1   2   0 wz--n- 931.09g 48.00m
```

This should be the volume group (stack-volumes) Openstack uses to create volume and volume snapshots. In order to create more volumes and larger volumes you have to increase the capacity of the volume group. In this case the volume group to extend is "stack-volumes".

Let's create a partition with 50GB.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=cinder-volumes bs=1 count=0 seek=50G
losetup /dev/loop3 cinder-volumes
fdisk /dev/loop3
```

And at the fdisk prompt, enter the following commands:

```
n
p
1
ENTER
ENTER
t
8e
w
```

Create a physical volume

```
root@stratos1:~# pvcreate /dev/loop3
  Physical volume "/dev/loop3" successfully created
```

Extend the volume group "stack-volumes".

```
root@stratos1:~# vgextend stack-volumes  /dev/loop3
```

Volume group "stack-volumes" successfully extended

Let's see the details about the available physical devices. You will see the new device listed down.

```
root@stratos1:~# pvs
  PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/loop0 stack-volumes lvm2 a-    10.01g 10.01g
  /dev/loop3 stack-volumes lvm2 a-    50.00g 50.00g
```

Now check the details of the volume groups by executing the vgdisplay command. You will see there is more free space (60GB since we added 50GB more) in the volume group `stack-volumes`.

```
root@stratos1:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               stack-volumes
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        3
  Metadata Sequence No  303
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                3
  Act PV                3
  VG Size               60.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              23040
  Alloc PE / Size       7680 / 30.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       15360 / 60.00 GiB
  VG UUID               bM4X5R-hC3V-zY5F-ZMVI-s7dz-Kpiu-tPQ2Zt
```